# how to create array of button in gtk+

Tags: c, arrays, gtk3

I want to create array of buttons in gtk+. So, how to modify 'gtkWidget *button' to create array of button. I have modified the declaration to 'gtkWidget (*button)[20]' and used this button in below code. But, it's showing an error.  " incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct GtkWidget *[20]’ from type ‘struct GtkWidget * ’"

```
gtkWidget (*button)[20];
static char *values[100] = 

 {  "127.0.0.1",   "Idle",
 "192.168.73.129", "Idle", 
 "192.168.73.130", "Idle",
 "192.168.73.131", "Idle",
 "192.168.73.132", "Idle",
 "192.168.73.129", "Idle",
 "192.168.73.131", "Idle", };

for(i=0; i < 6; i++) {
for( j=0; j < 2; j++) {
  button1[pos] = gtk_button_new_with_label(values[pos]);
  gtk_table_attach_defaults(GTK_TABLE(table), button1[pos], j, j+1, i+1, i+2 );
  pos++;
} }
```

Comment: so want like `(gktbutton*)[20]` or need to look up at https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/unstable/guitar-tuner.c.html.en

Comment: Also what about `GtkWidget *button[x][y];`

Comment: I've been checked for (gktbutton*)[20] but it's not working.

Comment: can you try second one `GtkWidget *button[x][y]` ?

Comment: No, i've not tried but i think it's for 2D array button?

Comment: yes try like `for (i = 0; i < x; i++){for (j = 0; j < y; j++){           board[i][j] = gtk_button_new ();}                                                                                                                                                    }`

Comment: welcome friend, glad it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gtkWidget (*button)[20];` it's invalid assignment internally it's like `‘struct GtkWidget *[20]’` means array subscript pointer.

create array of buttons in simple way like

```
GtkWidget *buttons[3][3];
  for (i=0;i<3; i++)
    for (j=0;j<3; j++) 
          buttons[i][j] = gtk_button_new ();
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, GtkTable is deprecated in Gtk3, so you should use a GtkGrid instead.

Second, you don’t really need to store those widgets in an array, so simply iterating through the values list and create two buttons in each steps is a bit better approach:

```
GtkWidget *ip_button,
          *status_button;
gchar *values[] = {
    "127.0.0.1",      "Idle",
    "192.168.73.129", "Idle", 
    "192.168.73.130", "Idle",
    "192.168.73.131", "Idle",
    "192.168.73.132", "Idle",
    "192.168.73.129", "Idle",
    "192.168.73.131", "Idle",
};

for (i = 0; i < value_count; i += 2) {
    ip_button = gtk_button_new_with_label(values[i]);
    gtk_grid_attach(grid, button, i, 0, 1, 1);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(ip_button_callback), NULL);

    status_button = gtk_button_new_with_label(values[i + 1]);
    gtk_grid_attach(grid, button, i, 1, 1, 1);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(button), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(status_button_callback), ip_button);
}
```

In the `ip_button_callback()` function you can use `gtk_button_get_label()` to get the IP address associated with the button, while in `status_button_callback()` you can get the label of the button passed as `user_param`.

A much elegant solution may be to store these buttons in a GHashTable using the IP addresses as table keys, but that takes a bit more thinking on the design (and needs a lot more background information).